# Iconos de tabbar (App híbrida html)

Tags: html, framework7

Buenas noches. 
Soy nuevo en esto de la programación, y estaba probando para hacer una app híbrida con Framework7, que tiene layouts para hacer apps y lo estoy usando para empezar. Quiero probar a empezar haciendo una app con un tabbar en la parte de abajo, y el código que ellos te dan es digamos con iconos demo, pero yo no sé como hacer para poner mis propios iconos, ya que ellos te ponen: demo-tabbar-icon-4 pero poniendolo yo no funcionan. Os dejo su código para ver si sabéis decirme. Muchas gracias!

```
<div class="toolbar tabbar tabbar-labels">
<div class="toolbar-inner">
    <a href="#tab1" class="tab-link active">
        <i class="icon demo-icon-1"></i>
        <span class="tabbar-label">Label 1</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#tab2" class="tab-link">
        <i class="icon demo-icon-2">
            <span class="badge bg-red">5</span>
        </i>
        <span class="tabbar-label">Label 2</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#tab3" class="tab-link">
        <i class="icon demo-icon-3"></i>
        <span class="tabbar-label">Label 3</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#tab4" class="tab-link">
        <i class="icon demo-icon-4"></i>
        <span class="tabbar-label">Label 4</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Ese es el que ellos te dan. El caso es que cambio "icon demo-icon-4" que esta en  por el nombre de las imágenes que tengo yo guardadas y no funciona. Supongo que estoy diciendo una tontería y que claramente es un fallo tonto pero como ya he dicho soy nuevo y no tengo mucha idea..

Por si sirve, el código que tengo yo, con nombres de las bar, y con los nombres de las imágenes que no funcionan:

```
<div class="toolbar tabbar tabbar-labels">
    <div class="toolbar-inner">
    <a href="#view-1" class="tab-link active">
    <i>"crown-7.png"</i>
    <span class="tabbar-label">Information</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#view-2" class="tab-link">
    <i class="crown-7"></i>
    <span class="tabbar-label">Inbox</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#view-3" class="tab-link">
    <i class="icon tabbar-demo-icon-3"><span class="badge bg-red">4</span></i>
    <span class="tabbar-label">Upload</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#view-4" class="tab-link">
    <i class="icon tabbar-demo-icon-4"></i>
    <span class="tabbar-label">Photos</span>
    </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Pues eso, muchísimas gracias a todos!

Comment: incluye el `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">` en el `head`

Comment: y reemplaza los  `<i class="icon tabbar....">` por estos `<i class="material-icons">add</i>` esa palabra la cambias por cualquier icono.

Comment: https://material.io/icons/ toda la lista de iconos de materialize PD: Los que tiene un espacio, como por ejemplo "find replace" se le agrega un guion bajo "find_replace"

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Héctor!!